# Open URL in new tab on button click in asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have an URL https://resident.uidai.gov.in/offlineaadhaar 
Whenever I open in a browser, it opens properly without any issue.

But the issue arises when we redirect to the above URL from my asp.net application on button click.

I have used the following options:

1. a href tag
2. Response.redirect
3. postback url of button
4. window.open in javascript.

All gives me `403 forbidden` error.

Following is the code snippet:

1) window.location.href("https://resident.uidai.gov.in/offlineaadhaar");

2) a href="https://resident.uidai.gov.in/offlineaadhaar" target="_blank"

3) string url = "https://resident.uidai.gov.in/offlineaadhaar";
        Response.Write("window.open('" + url + "');");

4) string url = "https://resident.uidai.gov.in/offlineaadhaar";
   Response.RedirectPermanent(url);

Comment: The link is still broken.

Comment: on your anchor tag add property `target="_blank"`

Comment: Can you write down your code for all you tried?

Comment: @vikscool  Tried but not working. Its gives 403 forbidden error..When u type url directly in browser it works but its gives error when u redirect from application.

Comment: @ShahNidhi are you using `IE`(*as your default browser in Visual studio*) as I think the website not accessible from it. Even though they have mentioned that their website will support any `IEv10+`. So, try it in chrome/firefox.